# tomcat is not starting up in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I start my tomcat in eclipse initially it starts (Green errow - went away - Red appears and consol shows "server startup in 535 ms") in status bar still it says "Starting tomcat v6.0". In some time timeout is done and says server failed to start. I increase timeout to 100 ms from defaultone. Still same issue. Do anyone have any idea?

I tried and applied various solutions given in stackoverflow and other website for this but all failed.
Tomcat starts outside of eclipse.
check netstat and compare no conflicts of any port. (Change all necessary port from eclipse)
Added tomcat-juli.jar (ONE OF THE SOLUTION).
I have not configured a single project yet. Just starting tomcat.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @VarunAchar Yes, I was able to figure it out. Currently I am not able to remember one application (software) running behind. (install by network admin) for IP/Port related configuration. That was causing an issue. Not remembering the exect software name but it's cause of that software only. Not an issue of tomcat. Sorry for late reply but I just open my account today after a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Currently I am not able to remember one application (software) running behind. (install by network admin) for IP/Port related configuration.